# How to get Broadcast intent of changing date format

Tags: android

I want to do some thing on changing date format of android Device.

But I do't find any broadcast action or any method for achieving it.

Comment: ACTION_TIME_CHANGED, ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED, ACTION_TIME_TICK ...

Answer (score 1):

Create a [content observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) and listen to changes to [`Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#DATE_FORMAT)